American horror/thriller with hidden tape recorder playing the sound of a crying baby
I'm looking to try and find this American horror/thriller film, probably from the 90s, I can remember only parts of, but searching around hasn't been successful.
I think the movie is based mostly in a large house out in the middle of nowhere. It involves a woman who keeps hearing the sound of a baby crying somewhere in the house (I don't know if she actually has a baby or not, but she can either never find the source of the crying, or she reaches her child and finds that they are not crying). The crying starts to drive her crazy, and eventually she discovers a strange wire on the staircase  of the house. She follows this wire to find a hidden room in which there is a tape recorder/speaker system playing out the sound of a baby crying. It is also possible that there was someone living secretly in the house, or specifically in this room.
I also think there is part of the movie (probably the ending) where two people are fighting on top of the house, and the "bad guy" ends up getting pushed off and falls to his death.
Does anyone have any ideas?

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification.  What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

The movie you are describing is a 1995 made-for-TV film called Remember Me

rottentomatoes

Still recovering from a breakdown caused by the death of her son two
  years earlier, Menly Nichols (Kelly McGillis) convalesces in the old
  mansion where her husband Adam (Cotter Smith) grew up. The emotionally
  fragile Menly is having difficulty enough adjusting to her somewhat
  dank surrounding when she begins to be haunted by an eerie, faraway
  voice. Could the sounds be merely a manifestation of her trauma and
  guilt feelings--or are they caused by the ghost of her son,
  desperately trying to contact her? Mary Higgins Clark, this filmed-for-TV 
  gothic melodrama made its CBS network debut on November 19, 1995.

Plot keywords IMDB:masion, cable, falling off a balcony, secret room, tape recording, child crying, loss of son
Promo

Thank you, that looks like it! I'd been trying to find this film for years.
